# Retrieving languages and stargazers of GitHub repos

Tags: github, google-bigquery, github-archive

I'm new to SQL and GitHubArchieve and trying to get the list of languages and stargazers of the popular repositories on GitHub.

The information I'm looking for are repo id, repo languages (languages + percentage), repo stargazers (and their timezones).

So, my solution to this was by retrieving the most popular repositories and then parsing the `languages_url` and `stargazers_url` to get their information.

I started with the following query to retrieve the popular repositories:

```
SELECT
  repo.name,
  repo.id,
  repo.url,
  payload,
  COUNT(*) watch_count,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.watch.action.repository.languages_url') AS repo_languages_url 
FROM [githubarchive:month.201601],
WHERE type = 'WatchEvent'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,6
HAVING watch_count >= 2000 ORDER BY watch_count DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

The payload for the watch events was just: `{"action":"started"}` so I didn't get any information about the languages and the contributors of the repositories.

Any suggestions to get the information I'm looking for? 
Is there any way for retrieving that information without parsing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out github_repos dataset in bigquery-public-data project - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github

Comment: Yes, I have checked that already. I still don't understand why the payload for the WatchEvent is just {"action":"started"} . Any clue?